# d3.pack(): multiple parent circles each with a unique color

Tags: javascript, css, d3.js, layout

I anm new to d3 and I would like to create a d3.pack. I am looking for tutorial and example of codes, but all the ones I find have a single parent circle whereas, I would like several of them like on this [image](http://d3indepth.com/img/layouts/pack.png) (except the "continent" circles would each have a different color).

I wonder how it can be done. I am new to .js and D3 so I tried to add another first level item in the JS object, but apparently it doesn't work that way.

SO now I am trying with a single first parent, but with a `"fillopacity":"0.0",` so that it will be transparent, but again I couldn't make it works.

Here is my [try](https://jsfiddle.net/tzpoqcno/2/)  (inspired by [http://d3indepth.com](http://d3indepth.com/layouts/#pack-layout))

Some bits of the code:

```
var data = {
  "name": "A1",
  "fill": "red",
  "fillopacity":"0.0",
  "children": [
    {
      "name": "B1",
      "fill": "blue",
      "children": [... code cut ...]
     },
    {
      "name": "B2",
      "value": 200,
      "fill": "yellow"
    },
     {
      "name": "B3",
      "value": 200,
      "fill": "green"
    }
  ]
};

d3.select('svg g')
  .selectAll('circle')
  .data(rootNode.descendants())
  .enter()
  .append('circle')
  .attr('cx', function(d) { return d.x; })
  .attr('cy', function(d) { return d.y; })
  .attr('r', function(d) { return d.r; })
  .attr('fill', function(d) { return d.fill; })
  .attr('fill-opacity', function(d) { return d.fillopacity; })
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You almost had it.  Your extra properties are in `d.data` though:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<head>
  <title>Pack layout</title>
</head>


<body>
  <svg width="320" height="320">
    <g></g>
  </svg>

  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/d3/4.2.2/d3.min.js"></script>
  <script>
var data = {
  "name": "A1",
  "fill": "red",
  "fillopacity":"0.0",
  "children": [
    {
      "name": "B1",
      "fill": "blue",
      "children": [
        {
          "name": "C1",
          "value": 100,
          "fill": "red"
        },
        {
          "name": "C2",
          "value": 300,
          "fill": "red"
        },
        {
          "name": "C3",
          "value": 200,
          "fill": "red"
        }
      ]
    },
    {
      "name": "B2",
      "value": 200,
      "fill": "yellow"
    },
     {
      "name": "B3",
      "value": 200,
      "fill": "green"
    }
  ]
};

var packLayout = d3.pack()
  .size([300, 300]);

var rootNode = d3.hierarchy(data)

rootNode.sum(function(d) {
  return d.value;
});

packLayout(rootNode);

d3.select('svg g')
  .selectAll('circle')
  .data(rootNode.descendants())
  .enter()
  .append('circle')
  .attr('cx', function(d) { return d.x; })
  .attr('cy', function(d) { return d.y; })
  .attr('r', function(d) { return d.r; })
  .attr('fill', function(d) { return d.data.fill; })
  .attr('fill-opacity', function(d) {
    return d.data.fillopacity;
  })

  </script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: So that's the way to do it, Too bad it's not possible to have several first level circles. Just a last question, how can I know which attributes are in d.data? I look around but couldn't find an explanation.

Comment: @Enora, the `d3.pack` manipulates the flare data to have position and radius information.  The original data structure (what was passed into `d3.pack`) is preserved in the `.data` property.